# Running exe with GUI into Azure WorkerRole

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, createprocess

I'm having a problem running a client application on an Azure Worker Role.

To run it programatically, I try to use System.Diagnostic.Process() and CreateProcessWithLogonW() and CreateProcessAsUser() and always get faults with following error log:

```
Faulting application SumatraPDF.exe, version 2.1.1.0, time stamp 0x50671ddb, 
faulting module USER32.dll, version 6.0.6002.18541, time stamp 0x4ec3e39f, 
exception code 0xc0000142, fault offset 0x0006f52f, process id 0x84c, 
application start time 0x01cdaec9ec56418e.
```

Is there some way to programmatically run a client application hosted on a Worker Role? If I remote into the VM and run the application with the local command prompt it runs without errors.

Comment: What happens if you remote into the VM and run the application from a command prompt?

Comment: If I remote into the VM application runs without error.

Comment: Is your worker role running elevated or not? If it's not already, you might try temporarily running it elevated to figure out if it's a permissions thing or not. Beyond that, I'm about out of easy ideas.

Comment: Yes, worker role running elevated. I'll try to solve this about 3 weeks. And absolutely no ideas about it. I can prepare example out of main project which demonstrate this problem.

Comment: Well, it may be as simple as your title suggests; perhaps the attempt to present a GUI is causing the error. You might want to build a simple Windows service that attempts the same thing so you can make sure the problem can be reproduced locally. (This will save a lot of time as you test things.)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the same from an elevated Task instead. I've seen marked differences in performance in processes that are created with Process.Start during the worker role lifecycle and a Task. It also looks like a GDI issue in your response so it may be worth sharing your ProcessInfo.